# ¿Como se imprimen los demás nodos del árbol binario?

Tags: c++, nodos

Alguien me puede ayudar diciéndome como funciona este código para mostrar un árbol?, entiendo que primero comprueba si no esta vació, en caso de no estarlo pasa a el else, donde se vuelve a llamar pero esta vez con la parte derecha del árbol, se llama así mismo hasta llegar a el ultimo nodo hoja de la derecha, y como el ultimo nodo hoja apunta a null, mi pregunta es ¿Que pasa cuando se llama a si misma y entra a el if en la recursion? no me retorna, nada pero ahora como hace el programa para mostrar los nodos que están en la izquierda? gracias.

```
void MostrarArbol(Nodo *arbol, int cont){
if(arbol == NULL){
    return;
}
else{
    MostrarArbol(arbol->der, cont+1);

    for(int i=0; i<cont; i++){
        cout<<"   ";
    }
    cout<<arbol->dato<<"\n";
    MostrarArbol(arbol->izq, cont+1);
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: A como esta la pregunta, lo mejor que te puedo decir es que trates de seguir el
código "a mano". O que trates de verlo en un debugger, de esa forma veraz como
lo hace.